# What is the difference between Original Hire date and Continuous Hire date in Workday?

Tags: workday-api

What is the difference between Original Hire date and Continuous Hire date in Workday? I am currently working in WD support and want to know what is the difference between these two. How these are impacting payroll?

Answer (score 0):

Original hire date and Continues hire date will be same for worker hired for first time.

If worker was hire in past and terminated, now rehired then Original hire date will be equal to terminated user hire date and Continues hire date will be equal to current hire date.

for payroll you have to check with your tenant setup.